# Registration and login via PDO

Tags: performance, php, pdo

don't blame me I am trying to learn, the code works but I am not
sure it is well optimized. Please tell me if you see something wrong.
My goal is to achieve most optimized code (and learn something in
between).

1. User register -> check if username or email exists , if not = insert into database
2. User login -> check database if username exists, then verify password, let them in :)

#### Login.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
....
<form....>// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974613/pdo-php-check-if-row-exist
    $stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        if( $row ) {
            if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password'])) {
                // ==============================
                session_regenerate_id(); // https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php
                $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true; // Store data in session variables
                $_SESSION["id"] = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];  
                    //$form->printr($_SESSION); // for debug 
                header("location: profile.php");  
                // ==============================
            } else { $form->error_message("Паролата не е вярна."); } // User ok , pass not valid    
        }  else { $form->error_message("Няма такъв акаунт в системата."); } // No such user         
    $link = null; // close pdo connection
```

#### Register.php

```
<?php
session_start();
...
<form...>//
/* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974613/pdo-php-check-if-row-exist
        $sql = 'SELECT 1 from table WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1';
        //$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) from table WHERE param = ?'; // for checking >1 records
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        if($stmt->fetchColumn()) echo 'found';
*/ 
        $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT 1 from users WHERE username=? or email=? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute(array($username,$email));
        if ($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0) { 
           $form->add_to_errors('Името или Имейла вече е зает, моля опитайте с друг.'); // Username taken
        } else { 
           $data = ['name' => $username,'email'  => $email, 'pass' => $password]; // INSERT INTO DATABASE 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (:name, :email, :pass)"; 
        // ===========================================================
        $stmt= $link->prepare($sql); //$stmt->execute($data);
        if ($stmt->execute($data)) {  //success 
            $form->success_message("Добре дошъл в системата: <b>".$username."</b>"); 
            //session_regenerate_id();  
        } else { $form->add_to_errors('Проблем със заявката за регистрация, моля опитайте по-късно или се свържете с администратор.'); } // failed 
        } 
    $link = null; // close pdo connection
```

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking why nobody is responding to your question? Well, I think it's because there's not much to comment on. You've used prepared statements and the standard way to hash passwords. If there's anything to say, it would be that your code looks a bit messy. Indentation could be better and lots of the comments are superfluous. Apart from that, you've given us very little to work with.

Comment: I'am interested in best possible way to optimize the code, to check if user exists in db, and for registration form too(best optimizations)
there are tons of examples and all are different.
Some use fetchAll others rowCount , some use SELECT 1 in query other LIMIT 1
all all do the same , but i wounder what is the best

Comment: "Optimize" is not a very accurate word. You could optimize for readability, speed or security. Some people even consider the shortest code as being optimal. It basically means you want the best code, whatever that is. I've given you two suggestions: _"Indentation could be better and lots of the comments are superfluous."_ Does that help?

Comment: What you think of this i kinda change some of the code https://pastebin.com/CkggrHSA